# click and select value of javascript drop down menu using python 2 selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to click on following code and select value "SLAHOLD"

```
<div aria-live="polite" id="mx5050_holder" class="bc"><input aria-required="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" id="mx5050" class="fld text cbt  ibfld fld_req" ctype="textbox" li="mx5051" liclick="1" maxlength="10" style=";width:75.0px;" sue="1" readonly="readonly" type="text" title="New Status" value="" ov="" work="1" fldinfo="{&quot;length&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;inttype&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;eventpriority&quot;:1,&quot;required&quot;:true}" originalvalue="" prekeyvalue="" stoptcclick="false" keydown="true"></div>
```

Here is javascript code, which I need to select from above menu:

```
javascript: topLevelMenus['shared'].menuClick({"id":"0_SLAHOLD_OPTION","text":"SLA Hold","value":"0_SLAHOLD_OPTION","target":"incident_STATUS_menus","event":"click"});
```

I tried few options but it rather does nothing, here is what I got now:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mx5050']").click()   
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='menuholdertd']").click()  
time.sleep(2)
```

Python version is 2.7.5

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the URL that contains that combobox?

Comment: Hmm also, I don't see the id "menuholdertd" in the HTML snippet you posted. Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of my earlier comments, what happens if you try sending these keys to the combobox:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mx5050")

elem.send_keys("SLA Hold")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alichino. I cannot paste link as this is internal website. Here is what I got after pasting part you've suggested into the script:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slaholder.py", line 171, in <module>
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mx5050")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"mx5050"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.6.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

Comment: How about id "mx5050_holder"? I have a suspicion that that might be a dynamic id, but perhaps not...

Comment: So I have added those two lines:

Comment: elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mx5050_holder")

    elem.send_keys("SLA Hold")

Comment: and I got this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"mx5050_holder"}